# "tr1/cstdio: No such file or directory" error appearing when trying to run c code in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

hi I have been trying to find the solution to this error but most solutions are only for linux. i am currently using microsoft.
i have installed mingw and have installed gcc but it still seems to show this error
here is my error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuePW.png)
here is my config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iWZd.png)

i tried reinstalling windows sdk and changing path but i still get the error.
when i clicked on the error and went to look it sent me to this page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NchgN.png)
i dont know why it contains the line for tr1/cstdio even though i am using c and not c++

Comment: can you compile your program within mingw with `gcc polo.c`, if not it is a mingw problem and not VSC

Comment: why post images of text, hard to type and search for